# Memory not releasing when calling dealloc on NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory-leaks, dealloc

I am trying to debug a memory leak within my code (2.5mb) and it seems to be pointing to _`prepareResultsFromResultSet` within `NSFetchedResultsController`. I have 2 viewControllers (A & B), viewController B is pushed on to the navigationController from viewController A.

In B I am performing an `NSFetchRequest` using `NSFetchedResultsController` as follows:

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sMapSlug;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andMapSlug: (NSString *)slug;
```

**.m**

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andMapSlug: (NSString *)slug
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.sMapSlug = [NSString stringWithString:slug];
    }
    return self;
}
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
        return _fetchedResultsController;

    Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedSingleton];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DescriptionEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[singleton managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"map.sName" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"map.sSlug LIKE %@", self.sMapSlug];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:8];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:myPredicate];

    // Finally check the results
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[singleton managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (DescriptionEntity *desc in fetchedObjects)
    {
        NSLog(@"Maps present in database: %@", desc.map.sName);
    }        

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[singleton managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Test1"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    //[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:NULL];
    [theFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sort release];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest];
}
```

Everything is loaded in fine using the fetchRequest and I can access my data if need be, however I have taken this out for now so I know none of the data from the `NSFetchedRequestController` is being used. When I go back on the navigation stack the dealloc for controller B is called, and I perform the following:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    [_fetchedResultsController release];
    [sMapSlug release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

When I take heap shots of this within Instruments I see the following data stay after the dealloc is called:

[image]

If I go back in to controller B again, another set of this memory is added and never removed. However, if I do this a 3rd time the amount does not increment. I am presuming that there is some sort of caching going on, can anyone tell me how to remove this data or how to correctly deallocate an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

If you need any more information feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you should not worry about memory management in Core Data. Yes, under the hood a caching mechanism is involved.

Anyway, there are two different methods to "dismiss" the memory.

The first is `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` method. Passing to it `NO`, it allows to prune the object graph. In other words, it throws away any changed data that has not been saved to the store.

Override `willTurnIntoFault` and `didTurnIntoFault` to see it in action.

The other is to call `reset` on a managed context. Obviosly, this removes all the objects the context contains.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will give it a try in a minute. I just need to clear the cache as I'm using NSFetchedResultsController in more than one viewcontroller and they all seem to be retaining memory. I will give it a go and mark as answer if it works, thanks for the help once again.

Comment: Sorry to only just get back, this doesn't seem to be freeing the memory for some reason. I am writing a new project that is stripped out completely and every time I pop the current view it leaves the original 256kb of sqlite3memmalloc. This doesn't seem to grow each time so I'm guessing it's just my original code has other memory issues. Is there anyway to completely clear all the sqlite3 memallocs?

Comment: Playing with your suggestions again and this did in fact work for me. I was just calling it in the wrong place, and it's taken my memory usage down dramatically. The issue lies in the creation of my entities, as I am loading images / sounds it is keeping the memory ref to them. Calling this frees up the memory again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever call dealloc yourself, not even on your own objects. This is something the system does it self.

Comment: I thought you were meant to dealloc any retained pointers? I wasn't using ARC for this project.

Comment: Nope, you call release, you never ever call dealloc, that throws the whole system into a bad state